# Is it possible to to access the underlying Window type in wxHaskell?

Tags: c++, haskell, ogre3d

What I'm wondering is if it is possible to get the bare metal C++ Window type from the wxWidgets port to Haskell. I've looked through the library's documentation and so far have been unsuccessful.

What I'm planning to do with it is pass it to a C function (which then interfaces with C++ code) to render some 3D graphics using OGRE3D. I know that a small binding for OGRE exists in Haskell all ready, but all of the tutorials are written in C++ and I am a newb to OGRE. I don't want to translate the tutorials to Haskell while I'm still learning the library.

If this isn't possible, what other course of action would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late I know, but try:

```
WIN_TYPE uiWindow = nil;
Ogre::RenderWindow *ogreWindow = Ogre::Root::getSingleton().getAutoCreatedWindow();
ogreWindow->getCustomAttribute("WINDOW", &uiWindow);
```

The only thing you need to change is WIN_TYPE to whatever wxWidgets uses.

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less the solution that I came up with. However, I decided that I would use a simpler UI library; wxWidgets is overkill for my purposes. I found out that the function `frame` more or less gives you the C type, for those who are interested.